# codeigniter work only with index.php in the url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a CI installation which has routes

```
$route['signin']="auth/login";
$route['logout']="auth/logout";
$route['signup']="auth/register";
```

my ci installation resides inside `www.domain.com/app/`

when i goto this url , it routes to www.domain.com/app/signin/ but it shows

```
The requested URL /www.domain.com/app/signin was not found on this server.
```

but when i manually insert index.php

```
www.domain.com/app/index.php/signin
```

then it opens.

What can be the issue?I have configured htaccess.

This ci installation was in another server and I transafered it to this new server.I kept the base url blank.

htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: where is the .htaccess code

Comment: Have step by step solution:http://goo.gl/3jfW8f

Comment: Sometimes it depends on your hosting server. Could you please mention your hosting server provider name.

Comment: Then your .htaccess looks good. May be you have some other issue.

Comment: @user3637105 set RewriteBase/app/ to your subdirectory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This ci installation was in another server and I transferred it to this new server.

Based on it working on another server, it appears the new server does not have the [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) Apache setting configured to enable the htaccess, meaning your htaccess is disabled or ignored. Or the new server is a non-Apache web server, which doesn't recognize htaccess at all.

Comment: Mine is apache.SO how do I enable the htaccess ?Any?

Comment: Click on the `AllowOverride` link in the answer for how to enable it. To give full access for htaccess, use `AllowOverride All` in your httpd.conf file (in the `<Directory>` section).

Comment: This is it, ESPECIALLY  if it's an AWS EC2 server. This video shows how to change it quickly with SSH ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44vXMxHThT0

Answer (score 1):

You need update **config.php** to this

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and
| path to your installation.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = 'http://domain.com/app/';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = ''; // Remove index.php
```

Now **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

# RewriteBase /
RewriteBase /app/

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase/app/

# Add www in the start of URL if user leave
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Prevent CI index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

# Prevent user access to the CI system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# Prevent user access to the CI application folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

set `RewriteBase` like this `RewriteBase/app/`